# how do you create a joi schema to verify a json file format?

Tags: json, schema, joi

If i had the below format for a json file which is supposed to model a chemistry experiment, how do i create a joy schema to validate the json file format? there are basic examples i've seen that cover the joi schema syntax for non-nested structures, but the one below is nested and i'm not sure how to format the joi schema. Any suggestions?

```
{
  "injection": {
    "volume": {
      "value": 20,
      "unit": "MicroLiter"
    },
    "number": 1,
    "location": {
      "vial": "1",
      "plate_row": "A",
      "plate_column": "1"
    }
```

Comment: This would a very basic validation schema, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very simple use case of joi schema validation. For the above JSON

the nested schema is:

```
Joi.object().keys({
  injection: Joi.object().keys({
    number: Joi.number().required(),
    volume: Joi.object().keys({
      value: Joi.number().required(),
      unit: Joi.string().required()
    }).required(),
    location: Joi.object().keys({
      vial: Joi.string().required(),
      plate_row: Joi.string().required(),
      plate_column: Joi.string().required()
    }).required()
  })
});
```

Please let me know if this works.